# how to append values to lists in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I, have a dictionary say `{0:[1,2,3],1[1,2,3],2:[1,2,3],3:[1,2,4],4:[1,2,4],5:[1,2,4]}`. there are some duplicate values but the keys are different. when i append a value to list corresponding to key 0 python also adds the value to other duplicates what i don't need.

my code :-

```
for k, v in f.items(): 
    if k == 0:
        v.append(1)
```

result:-

```
{0:[1,2,3,1],1[1,2,3,1],2:[1,2,3,1],3:[1,2,4],4:[1,2,4],5:[1,2,4]}
```

what i want is :-

```
{0:[1,2,3,1],1[1,2,3],2:[1,2,3],3:[1,2,4],4:[1,2,4],5:[1,2,4]}
```

Comment: are you assigning the values to the same list?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the point of looping over the dict just to find a particular index? This defeats the purpose of the data structure. Is `f[key].append(foo)` not working? Also, if your dict is just sequential integer values, a list is much more efficient and semantically correct. Lastly, I don't think your code would produce the result you show unless the values were aliases, in which case you should show a [mcve] of how the dict is really created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your dictionary is faulty. It should be like this:

```
f={0:[1,2,3],1:[1,2,3],2:[1,2,3],3:[1,2,4],4:[1,2,4],5:[1,2,4]}

for k,v in f.items():
    if k==0:
        v.append(1)

print(f)
```

Output: `{0: [1, 2, 3, 1], 1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 4], 4: [1, 2, 4], 5: [1, 2, 4]}`

Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Thank you. it is the case but i am not able to understand what caused the fault in dict. both look similar but at first i converted it from a enumerated list if lists.